# Navigation Within a Tab Inside a tabbed Page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, tabbedpage

[inside one tab i use this code and add button to navigate to another content page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uGK6.png)I make a tabbed page in Xamarin Forms And Inside tabbed page I take 4 content page for tab Inside those content page there are some button when I add click event on button . to navigate in another content page . button doesn't fire. Please provide some solution for this problem.

```
<NavigationPage Title="Home" IconImageSource="HomeGrey.png">
    <x:Arguments >
        <local:NewHomeScreen Title="Home" ></local:NewHomeScreen>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage Title="Pickup" IconImageSource="PickupGrey.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:PickupPage ></local:PickupPage>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage Title="Setting" IconImageSource="settings.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:NewSetting ></local:NewSetting>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Support" IconImageSource="SupportGrey.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:SupportPage ></local:SupportPage>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

Comment: <!-- inside one tab i use this code and add button to navigate to another content page-->
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" Spacing="14">
  <Button:SfButton  
   x:Name="Direction"
  Padding="0"
  BackgroundColor="#0094DE" 
  ImageSource="gps.png" 
  Text="Get directions" 
  TextColor="#FFFFFF"
  FontFamily="PoppinsMedium"
  FontSize="12"
  CornerRadius="4"
  ShowIcon="True"
  HasShadow="True"
  HeightRequest="42"
  Clicked="DummyButton_Clicked"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to the next tab of the `TabbedPage` on clicking button, you can try to use `EventHandler` to achieve this.

I achieved this function,you can refer to the following code:

**FirstPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage 
      {
         public event EventHandler<string> ButtonClickedHandler;

       public FirstPage ()
            {
                  InitializeComponent ();
            }

            private   void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
              ButtonClickedHandler?.Invoke(this, "topage2");
            }
      }
```

**FirstPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.FirstPage"
                   IconImageSource="test.png"
                   Title="Today">
      <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="Today's appointments go here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Button Text="navigate" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage 
      {
            public MainPage ()
            {
                  InitializeComponent ();

            tabPage1.ButtonClickedHandler += delegate (object obj,string str) {
                CurrentPage = tabPage2;
            }; 

        }
      }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage" 
            x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage"
            x:Name="tabbedPage"
            >
      <local:FirstPage   x:Name="tabPage1" />
      <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png"   x:Name="tabPage2">
            <x:Arguments>
                  <local:SecondPage />
            </x:Arguments>
      </NavigationPage>
    <local:ThirdPage x:Name="tabPage3"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

**Update:**

I did a test using your code, but it threw error `**System.InvalidCastException:** 'Specified cast is not valid.'` . Since the current page is a `ContentPage`, so you cannot cast it to `TabbedPage`.

If you want to navigate to another page instead of other tabs, you can try code:

```
 Navigation.PushAsync (new DeliveryDetailPaidPage());
```

Comment: private async void DummyButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((NavigationPage)(App.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage).CurrentPage).Navigation.PushAsync(new DeliveryDetailPaidPage());
        } // I am using this but the button event handler not execute

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check the updated part at the bottom of my answer.